# Azure Data Factory GUID problems

Tags: guid, azure-data-factory

I'm struggling with import from a Azure Database for MySQL to Azure SQL Database. My copy activity always fails on one column, that contains mixture of unique identifiers and text.
Example of the data:

| modified_user_id |
| --- |
| 3cf7716c-a759-59c6-bc93-57307e0eaaf4 |
| bd0c24c2-ca72-11e9-99a9-005056a673da |
| 1 |
| Administrator |
| 1 |

The data type in the source in Azure Database for MySQL is char(36).
The data type in the target in Azure SQL database is varchar(36).
I didn't design neither the source nor the target, I cannot influence them.

Here is the code of the copy activity:

```
{
    "name": "Copy data1",
    "type": "Copy",
    "dependsOn": [
        {
            "activity": "truncate accounts",
            "dependencyConditions": [
                "Succeeded"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "policy": {
        "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
        "retry": 0,
        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
        "secureOutput": false,
        "secureInput": false
    },
    "userProperties": [],
    "typeProperties": {
        "source": {
            "type": "AzureMySqlSource",
            "queryTimeout": "02:00:00"
        },
        "sink": {
            "type": "AzureSqlSink",
            "writeBehavior": "insert",
            "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false,
            "disableMetricsCollection": false
        },
        "enableStaging": false,
        "translator": {
            "type": "TabularTranslator",
            "mappings": [
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "modified_user_id"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "modified_user_id",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "inputs": [
        {
            "referenceName": "accounts",
            "type": "DatasetReference"
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "referenceName": "accounts_staging",
            "type": "DatasetReference"
        }
    ]
}
```

**The problem is: when the column contains only GUIDs, it works fine. When it contains at least one non-GUID string, it fails.**

Why on earth, when the data type of both source and target are text data types?

In the source dataset, the column looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "modified_user_id",
    "type": "char",
    "precision": 0,
    "scale": 0
}
```

In the target dataset the column looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "modified_user_id",
    "type": "varchar"
},
```

Comment: Hi, can you share the error you are getting?

Comment: Hi @NiharikaMoola-MT, it was something like "one of the items was in invalid format". I already solved the problem (will post it here). For some reason, the MySql connector thinks that 36 characters long string is always GUID. I used a workaround, I cast all these columns to char(37).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up casting all char(36) columns to char(37) - like that it works like charm. The MySQL connector in ADF really considers any 36 long character string from MySQL as GUIDs, if it contains anything else, it fails.